# What's a good C++98 callback-like mechanism that satisfies SOLID principles?

Tags: c++, oop, c++98

I am working with a project that compiles with C++98 and I am trying to refactor my code in order to make it more maintainable.

My starting code is like this:

```
void ClassA::parseIncomingData(char * buffer) {
    switch(buffer[0]) {
        case 0x0F:
            sendMessage("Reply to 0x0F");
    }
}
void ClassA::sendMessage(char * text) {
    ...
}
```

I want to move the parser code to a dedicated class to isolate the parsing logic from the rest of the code. So I did this change:

Created class `MessageParser`:

```
MessageParser::MessageParser(IMessageSender * messageSender) {
    this->messageSender = messageSender;
}
void MessageParser::parseBuffer(char * buffer) {
    ...
    messageSender->sendMessage("Reply");
}
```

Changed the original `ClassA`:

(`ClassA` implements `IMessageSender` interface)

```
void ClassA::parseIncomingData(char * buffer) {
    MessageParser * parser = new MessageParser((IMessageSender *)this);
    parser->parseBuffer(buffer);
    delete parser;
}
void ClassA::sendMessage(char * text) {
    ...
}
```

Is there a better option to call `MessageParser` with some kind of reference to the non-static callback function that is defined into `ClassA`?

Comment: What is the purpose of class A? Does any other class need to parse something? Is the parsing affected from which class it gets called?

Comment: For starters, the parser should be constructed in automatic scope, and not dynamic scope. Using dynamic scope here accomplish nothing useful whatsoever, except to create a memory leak in case an exception gets thrown. Secondly, presuming that the class properly inherits from the base class, the explicit cast also accomplishes nothing useful whatsoever, except to serve as fertile breeding grounds for undefined behavior if class hierarchy gets refactored in the future, and this requirement gets overlooked.

Comment: why is the method non-static? From the example is seems like `parseBuffer` should be static

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.
1) class A instantiates a receiving socket, so it's the class that can receive data from the network.
2) as of today, only this class needs to do this parsing.
3) the parsing is not affected. I expect that the packet could arrive from a different source someday and that the parsing can remain the same.
4) yes, parseBuffer could be static, but that does not change the problem here: the callback is not static and I don't want to create a dependency between ClassA and MessageParser.

Comment: SOLID covers a lot of ground.  Are you adding in TDD-style unit tests?  Are you looking at code coverage?  Are you using dependency injection rather than tight coupling of concrete objects?  Do you have some sort of inversion of control framework, or are you doing it manually (I'm not familiar with any for C++, so I'd do it manually)?

Comment: 1) Yes, I'd like to TDD-test the parser and to mock the callback provider.
2) Code coverage might be interesting someday.
3) I'm not using a DI framework but I like the idea, so I'd like to create the MessageParser by injecting the callback provider. I do this manually.

Comment: Can you upgrade from C++98 to C++11 (or current C++17)?  I ask only because for callbacks I've found `std::function` and lambdas to be very useful.  I'm not sure how C++98 capable Boost is these days.  If Boost still supports C++98, there is a lot of well thought out functionality available there.  Including Boost Signals2 (C++11 or later) for something analogous to C# events.

Comment: It would be a much cleaner abstraction if you decouple the message _parsing_ (text -> objects & relationships) from the message _response_ (`sendMessage`). Is there any message that does not result in a single call to `sendMessage`?